# reportlab Displaying radio buttons that are only non selected still have checkboxes

Tags: python, radio-button, reportlab

Attempting to create radio buttons with reportlab I thought I would display selected and non-selected to see the difference and they both appear the same as being checked. So now I'm confused, shouldn't the non selected one be empty?

I was following the tutorial from http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/05/29/creating-interactive-pdf-forms-in-reportlab-with-python/ and tried to just print out each radio box separate.

```py
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfform
from reportlab.lib.colors import magenta, pink, blue, green

c = canvas.Canvas('simple_radios.pdf')

c.setFont("Courier", 20)
c.drawCentredString(300, 700, 'Radio demo')
c.setFont("Courier", 14)
form = c.acroForm

def radiobutton(x, y, selected, name='radio1',value='value1'):
   return form.radio(name=name, tooltip='Field radio1',
               value=value, selected=selected,
               x=x, y=y, buttonStyle='check',
               borderStyle='solid', shape='square',
               borderColor=magenta, fillColor=pink, 
               textColor=green, forceBorder=True)

def create_simple_radios():
    #c.drawString(10, 650, 'Dog:')
    radiobutton(110, 650, True, name='radio2', value='value2')
    radiobutton(110, 600, False, name='radio2', value='value2')
    #c.drawString(10, 600, 'Cat:') 
    radiobutton(110, 550, False, name='radio3', value='value3')
    radiobutton(110, 500, True)
    radiobutton(110, 450, True)
    radiobutton(110, 400, False)
    #c.drawString(10, 550, 'Pony:')
    c.save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_simple_radios()
```

I Expected the radio buttons where selected=false to show up on the PDF as blank unchecked boxes.

Comment: Your code works for me (altough you don't have two boxes for `radio3` and this will raise an error, the buttons are blank unchecked boxes as `selected=false`). Which version of `ReportLab` are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.5.23. And sorry about that but even when I fix radio3 I still have 6 boxes that are all checked.